# Unable to create file with PHP on AWS (ubuntu)

Tags: php, file, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have EC2 on AWS. It runs Ubuntu. After instalation I used this command to change permitions :

```
sudo chown -R -v ubuntu /var/www/
```

And I use this PHP simple sample code to create file.

```
<?php
 $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
 $txt = "John Doe\n";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 $txt = "Jane Doe\n";
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 fclose($myfile);
?>
```

But I am not able to create file with PHP. Any solution ?

Comment: are you running the PHP script from the command line?

Comment: No, from php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the user or the group which executes the php scripts has permissions to right in this directory. This user is usually www-data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, I'm new to server and all about it. How can I get this informations, and how can I change it ?

Comment: I tried this command. "sudo usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu" , but answer from server is this : "sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set"

Comment: If you want to write in var/www/files, move to var/www and type: `sudo chown www-data:ubuntu files` . This command will change the owner of the file. You need to do it using a user account with superuser privileges. Finally change the permission: `sudo chmod 750 files` (rwxr-x---)